# How can I get multiple independent RecyclerViews in a fragment to remember their scroll positions?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want the home screen of my app to contain three to five **carousels**. All of these carousels contain the same kind of data as cards (think the Netflix home screen, a vertical list of horizontal carousels, all of which contain cards representing films).

I have implemented these carousels using a custom **CarouselView** whose layout contains a RecyclerView with a `LinearLayoutManager` in `Horizontal` orientation. The home screen then has several of these CarouselViews embedded in a `NestedScrollView` in its layout.

Clicking on a card within one of these carousels navigates the user to another `Fragment` within the same `Activity`. I want it to be the case that when the user clicks the back button to return them to the home `Fragment`, all the carousels will be in the same position as they were to start when they left the `Fragment`. `LinearLayoutManager` should in theory take care of this all for me.

However, at present, only the scroll position of the last RecyclerView on the screen is saved. That is, if I scroll only the third carousel horizontally (to, say, card 3), click a card to navigate to a new `Fragment`, and then press back, the home `Fragment` now appears with all of the carousels scrolled to their third card. If I were to scroll only the first carousel (leaving the third carousel in its initial position), navigating away and then back would result in all carousels being reset to their original position.

How can I set up my carousels so that they will all remember their individual scroll position?

Here is a link to a small app illustrating my issue: https://github.com/flaheathrenn/multiple_carousels_android

EDIT: I believe the direct cause of the issue is that the RecyclerViews all have the same ID (because they all have the ID assigned to them within the layout of the CarouselView).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the following function to my CarouselView class:

```
fun setRecyclerViewId(id: Int) {
    cardCarousel.id = id
}
```

I then call it from within the HomeFragment on each CarouselView instance:

```
carouselView.setRecyclerViewId(R.id.carousel1_recyclerview_id)
carouselView2.setRecyclerViewId(R.id.carousel2_recyclerview_id)
```

using IDs set up in a `res/values/id.xml` file.

Now each RecyclerView has an independent and consistent ID, so their positions get correctly independently remembered.